Some PR for Bitcoin SE
Can we link to Bitcoin SE from the wiki?
Where would be appropriate to link from?
Can we get a link to be a sticky thread in the forums?
Any more ideas? OnlyOneTV?

bitcoin.stackexchange.com is now listed as the first community site on the very bitcoin.org frontpage. What more can you ask for? Almost feels like they have high hopes in us to bring back some sanity and seriousness into the community after all the recent craziness, hacking and drama.

@herzmeister - I didn't know we were first, awesome! I have high hopes with Bitcoin SE - for a long time it was very difficult for outsiders to understand what is going on with this crazy internet currency. No more!


Can we link to Bitcoin SE from the wiki?
Where would be appropriate to link from?

We've currently got a link from the forums page.  Do you think it should be somewhere more prominent?
It's worth noting that we've already got a link on the front page of bitcoin.org.  I believe Gavin added it the same day that we hit public beta.

Can we get a link to be a sticky thread in the forums?

Might be worth asking the mods about it.  Or eMansipater could edit his already-stickied introduction post to include a link.

Any more ideas?

Maybe ask the owner of weusecoins.com to put a link in the "getting started" section?

OnlyOneTV?

I am strongly opposed to letting Bitcoin.SE have any association with Bruce Wagner.

OK, let's not turn this into a "Bruce good or bad thread". If he does an episode about Bitcoin SE, that doesn't mean we're associated with him.

@ripper234: Seeking promotion on OOTV is a bad idea.  I'll leave it at that.

Anyone contacted weusecoins already?

Once this site matures a little I plan to link it from this post, which has over 40,000 views.

Is that offer still standing? ;)
